# Continuous integration with Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, automation, continuous-integration, ssrs-2008

I'm implementing a continuous integration environment with SVN and reporting services.

The reports are stored in the SVN repository. when a change occurs, they are automatically downloaded from the repository, and any file changed should be uploaded to the reporting services server.

**How could you automate the upload/update process for .rdl files?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to upload them via the [reporting services web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx). You'll have to generate a proxy and then write some code to read the reports from the local file system and upload them to the report server. You can use the [ReportingService2005.CreateReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.createreport(v=SQL.100).aspx) to do this.

You can also use the [rs Utility to write a script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152874.aspx). Here's a link to [Scripting Deployment and Administrative Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159720.aspx)

Comment: BTW even though the namespace says ReportingService2005, it does apply to the 2008 version